# Getting current url from a collection in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

If I want to get a page's url it's not exactly complicated:

```
page.url
```

However, what if I make a collection who's job it is to be used like an include instead of like a page?

If I make such a collection and ask for `page.url` it gives me the path to the collection instead of the path to the current url.

Is there a way to get the *real* current URL in Jekyll?

**Edit:** example

---

test.md:

```
---
title: Test page
permalink: /test/
---

Test page

{% for block in site.blocks %}
    {% if block.whatever %}
        {{ block.content }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

_blocks/block.md:

```
---
whatever: true
---

{% page.relative_path %}
```

---

Got:

```
Test page

/_blocks/block.md
```

---

Expected:

```
Test page

test.md
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using jekyll for a short time and I'm relying on collections to build my first static portfolio site. So far all my attempts when trying to get the path to the current url simply fails.

In order to achieve the desired result, I've used Jekyll Liquid filters.

#### Here is how you'd get the expected result you as per your question:

test.md:

```
---
title: Test page
permalink: /test/
---

Test page

{% for block in site.blocks %}
  {% if block.whatever %}
      {{ block.content }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

_blocks/block.md:

```
---
whatever: true
---

{{ page.relative_path | replace:'index.html', '' | remove: '_blocks/' | prepend: site.baseurl }}
```

#### Output on Test page

```
Test page

test.md
```

**Update:**

Perhaps the following is not the most straightforward method to get the path to the current url, but by defining `relative_path:` in the front-matter definitions of a document you'd also get the result you expect, of course this is something required on a per page basis.

```
--- 
whatever: true
relative_path: test.md
---

{% page.relative_path %}
```

So in this very specific case

`{% page.relative_path %}`

should output

```
test.md
```

#### A Jekyll's doc reminder:

As per [Jekyll's doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#collections), when you create a collection it becomes available via the `site` Liquid variable, pretty much like `site.posts` and `site.pages`, so you're able to use the available filters in most cases.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Has Jekyll behaviour changed in 3.0? From my example I can guess `page.relative_path` would have resulted in `/block.md` in your example

Comment: Humm, not sure actually, perhaps it did. I've just checked Jekyll -v = 3.0 , so the Liquid tag exist on my project.html layout in _Layouts and for my portfolio collection `page.relative_path` results in `_portfolio/test-project.md`, in any case, I think it's just a matter of adjusting the filter. This might not be a huge achievement but at least it worked when I was trying to make something very similar as what you describe here.